# Mahapps Metro Datagrid - High CPU usage & extremely slow performance with grouping

Tags: wpf, performance, datagrid, cpu-usage, mahapps.metro

i have a simple mahapps metro datagrid with 6 columns. i filled the datagrid with about 500 rows of data and tried grouping by a column header. WHile the grouping works the computer cpu usage shoots up to 99% and i cant do much else other than close the app.

The below is the grouping template used for the datagrid. I am not sure if it is the expander control or the datagrid itself that is buggy? any ideas?

I should specify the cpu usage goes up only when i try to expand the groups within the datagrid(Grpahic rendering issue?). by default i have them collapsed. also this happens with no extra styling or teplates applied to the datagrid or the columns.

```
 <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
    <GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate>
                <Expander IsExpanded="false">
                  <Expander.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                      <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Ghostwhite" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                      <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding ItemCount}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                  </Expander.Header>
                  <ItemsPresenter />
                </Expander>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
  </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```